# Compare elements in a list and change attributes

Tags: python, list

Aloha comrades,

I am a new to Python, so i am sorry if some of words/actions are pretty silly..

So, my task is to compare the elements inside of one list. 
If Element 1 is bigger than Element 2 i would like to mark this and continue to compare other elements with Element 1 (?Element1>Element3)...

At this point i am creating a simple class with my Processes:

```
processList = []
class Process:


def __init__(self, id, recvMsg):
    self.id = id
    self.recvMsg = recvMsg
```

Now i am generating the processes into the list..:

```
def CreateProcess():
   processList.append(Process(0,"NULL"))
   processList.append(Process(2,"NULL"))
   processList.append(Process(4,"NULL"))
   processList.append(Process(7,"NULL"))
   processList.append(Process(10,"NULL"))
```

And at the last step, i would like to compare the ID's of each element and if an another element is a bigger than element 1, i would like to change his recvMsg to "Bigger"

At this point, i have no idea how it should correctly happens.. So for now it's kind of a pseude code..

```
    for (j = 1; j < len(processList); j++)

        if processList[0].id < processList[j].id
           processList[j].recvMsg = "IsBigger"
```

Comment: So you only want to compare everything with only the first element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce). It's a builtin in Python 2, but you'll need to import it from `functools` in Python 3 (that's `from functools import reduce`).

```
def compare(a, b):
    if a.id < b.id:
        b.msg = 'IsBigger'
    return a

reduce(compare, processList)
```

You can then check:

```
>>> for proc in processList:
...     print((proc.id, proc.msg))
...
(0, 'NULL')
(2, 'bigger')
(4, 'bigger')
(7, 'bigger')
(10, 'bigger')
```

Answer (score 0):

## `for` loops

The `for` loop you used looks like you're a Java/JS/C programmer of some sort. Use this for loop:

```
for j in range(1, len(processlist)):
    if processList[0].id < processList[j].id:
           processList[j].recvMsg = "IsBigger"
```

You can just do that. `range(x, y)` is a generator which when iterated over will go through all integers starting at `x` and ending right before `y` (so `list(range(1, 5))` is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`)